# Выборка со "сложным" условием PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Имеется такая выборка
`SELECT queue,klid,type,shipno WHERE shipno = 25290`

Результат этой выборки;

| queue | klid | type | shipno |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27 | 1845 | 2 | 25290 |
| 27 | 1921 | 1 | 25290 |
| 28 | 1921 | 2 | 25290 |
| 29 | 1963 | 1 | 25290 |

Условие для выборки такое: `если количество повторяющихся queue > 1 то для каждого такого повторяющегося уникального queue оставляем только строку с type = 2`

В результате должены появится вот такой вывод

| queue | klid | type | shipno |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27 | 1845 | 2 | 25290 |
| 28 | 1921 | 2 | 25290 |
| 29 | 1963 | 1 | 25290 |

Подскажите как это реализовать в PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простой вариант: вам надо сначала создать таблицу для queue, где будут номера queue с повторами (28 и 29), а затем проверять на вхождение в неё.

Например, код может быть таким (привожу вместе с тестовой базой, сделанной для проверки). Учитите, что пишу на mySQL, но логика для PostgreSQL сохранится.
Можете повторяющийся кусок свести к алиасу, а также в условие WHERE добавить  shipno = 25290, если всё захотите одним запросом сделать.

```
CREATE TABLE calls(
    queue INT,
    klid INT,
    type INT,
    shipno INT    
);
INSERT INTO calls (queue,klid,type,shipno)
    VALUES
    (27,1845,2,25290),
    (27,1921,1,25290),
    (28,1921,2,25290),
    (29,1963,1,25290)
;
SELECT * FROM calls;

SELECT queue,klid,type,shipno
FROM calls
WHERE (queue NOT IN (
    SELECT queue
    FROM calls
    GROUP BY queue
    HAVING COUNT(queue) = 1
    ) AND type = 2)
    OR 
    queue IN (
    SELECT queue
    FROM calls
    GROUP BY queue
    HAVING COUNT(queue) = 1
    );
```

Результат:

```
Affected rows: 0

Affected rows: 4

Query result:
+-------+------+------+--------+
| queue | klid | type | shipno |
+-------+------+------+--------+
| 27    | 1845 | 2    | 25290  |
| 27    | 1921 | 1    | 25290  |
| 28    | 1921 | 2    | 25290  |
| 29    | 1963 | 1    | 25290  |
+-------+------+------+--------+
Affected rows: 4

Query result:
+-------+------+------+--------+
| queue | klid | type | shipno |
+-------+------+------+--------+
| 27    | 1845 | 2    | 25290  |
| 28    | 1921 | 2    | 25290  |
| 29    | 1963 | 1    | 25290  |
+-------+------+------+--------+
Affected rows: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы не указали название таблицы поэтому я использовал в ее качестве `some_table`

```
SELECT
    st1.queue,
    st1.klid,
    st1.type,
    st1.shipno
FROM some_table st1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT 
                       st2.queue, 
                       count(*) as cnt 
                FROM some_table st2 
                GROUP BY st2.queue) cnts
ON st1.queue = cnts.queue
WHERE 
      (cnts.cnt = 1) OR 
      (cnts.cnt > 1 AND st1.type = 2)
;
```

Что я тут сделал:

- я сделал запрос подсчитывающий количество строк сгруппированных по значению `queue`
- и используя результат данного вспомогательного запроса как временную таблицу - присоединил его к результатам выборки `some_table`, соединив их по значениям `queue`, после чего в основной выборке нам стало доступно количество строк с таким queue в таблице.
- после этого в условии можно указать

  - либо вы уникальны и идете в выборку как есть
  - либо вас много и выбираются только те, у которых `type=2`

вот и все.

Поступил именно так, ибо мне не очень хотелось делать несколько подзапросов в условии.
Вариант с `JOIN`ом казался мне чуть элегантнее

---

**Значения таблицы без дополнительных условий выборки**

| queue | klid | type | shipno |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5731 | 1 | 9764 |
| 2 | 9465 | 1 | 1346 |
| 2 | 6789 | 2 | 5863 |
| 3 | 2837 | 1 | 7584 |
| 4 | 4896 | 1 | 9568 |
| 4 | 3658 | 2 | 3265 |
| 5 | 7452 | 1 | 2451 |
| 6 | 2365 | 1 | 6458 |
| 6 | 4587 | 2 | 2552 |

**Результаты выполнения запроса в данном ответе**

| queue | klid | type | shipno |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5731 | 1 | 9764 |
| 2 | 6789 | 2 | 5863 |
| 3 | 2837 | 1 | 7584 |
| 4 | 3658 | 2 | 3265 |
| 5 | 7452 | 1 | 2451 |
| 6 | 4587 | 2 | 2552 |